# Create a second installDist task?

Tags: gradle, deployment, task

During development I am using a standard-function `installDist` (from the `application` plugin) in build.gradle:

```
installDist{}
```

... but I now want to have another task which installs/distributes/deploys a "production" version to the production location, which also incorporates the version into the directory structure. I tried this:

```
task deployOperativeVersion( type: installDist ) {
    destinationDir = file( "$productionDir/$version" )
}
```

Build failure output:

```
Build file '/home/mike/IdeaProjects/JavaFXExp2/Organiser/build.gradle' line: 98

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Organiser'.
> class org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync_Decorated cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class 
    (org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync_Decorated is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.
    internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @aec6354; java.lang.Class is in module
    java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

It appears that `installDist` is not a "type" as in `Test`.

How can I achieve this? Incidentally I would be really keen on having two separate tasks: to get `installDist` to run I've found that you only have to type `./gradlew inst` ... with a task called `deployXXX` it would be sufficient to type `./gradlew depl`.

I also tried this:

```
task deployOperativeVersion{
    installDist{
        destinationDir = file( "$operativeDir/$version" )
    }
}
```

... which doesn't seem to have done anything. Nor this:

```
task deployOperativeVersion{
    doFirst {
        installDist {
            destinationDir = file("$operativeDir/$version")
        }
    }
}
```

A bit later I thought I had indeed found the answer:

```
task deployOperativeVersion{
    dependsOn installDist{ destinationDir=file("$productionDir/$version")
}
```

... but to my amazement (will I ever get to a reasonable understanding of Gradle before Hell freezes over?), including this actually appears to influence the "routine" `installDist` task: specifically, it stops the latter from operating normally, and means that even when I run `installDist` the deployment/distribution/installation still goes to `productionDir/version`, rather than the default location.

So then I wondered about two tasks both of which are dependent on `installDist`:

```
task deployOperativeVersion{
    dependsOn installDist{ destinationDir=file("$productionDir/$version") }
}

task stdInstall{
    dependsOn installDist{ destinationDir=file("build/install") }
}
```

... haha, no joy: I run one and it deploys OK. I then run the other... and get an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':installDist'.
> The specified installation directory '/home/mike/IdeaProjects/JavaFXExp2/Organiser/build/install' is neither empty nor does it contain an installation for 'Organiser'.
  If you really want to install to this directory, delete it and run the install task again.
  Alternatively, choose a different installation directory.
```

... needless to say, this is NOT the case: under ...Organiser/build/install there is one directory only, Organiser, with /bin and /lib directories under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task should be declared as a `Sync` task, which is the actual type of the `installDist` task. The `application` plugin is using the `distribution` plugin. You can grab the content configuration from the `main` distribution, which is the source, or from the `installDist` task.

```
task deployOperativeVersion(type: Sync) {
    destinationDir = file("${productionDir}/${version}")
    with distributions.main.content
}
```

or

```
task deployOperativeVersion(type: Sync) {
    destinationDir = file("${productionDir}/${version}")
    with installDist
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I found the API doc for the application plugin at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html. But could you maybe just point me in the direction of where this `with` stuff is documented? I have this ambition that maybe one day I might be a bit less ignorant about Gradle.

Comment: It's part of the `CopySpec` interface (mentioned in the distribution section of the application plugin documentation you linked). The `CopySpec` interface contains most of the common configuration methods for copying files used in task types like `Copy`, `Sync`, `ProcessResources`, `Jar`, `War`, `Tar`, `Zip`, etc.